# DNS-Prefetch and Preconnect - One, or Both? Fallback?

Tags: html, dns

I've been reading up on using dns-prefetch and preconnect. Obviously they should be used, because every little bit helps.

dns-prefetch has a lot better support across browsers than preconnect. So my question is, if a browser doesn't support preconnect, does it fall back to a dns-prefetch? My thinking is preconnect is basically dns-prefetch with some extra sauce (tls negotiations, what not). But I could also see how that isn't the case.

Next, if I am wanting something to preconnect, but want to make sure the dns-prefetch at least works, should I include both? Is that optimal?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I was looking answer for the same question and i found this thread on reddit: https://www.reddit.com/r/webdev/comments/80w8c0/some_questions_regarding_preconnect_and/ and there was a link to a Twitter post: https://twitter.com/csswizardry/status/962313751818113024 which states:

Question:

> Performance experts, shall we use **dns-prefetch** or **preconnect**
>   for things like CDN?
>
> **preconnect** seems to have a bigger impact but has a lesser support. Can we use both safely?
>
> I can’t seem to find a definitive answer as to which to use when.

Answer:

> Use both. Put your preconnects first.

Comment: Using both like `<rel="preconnect dns-prefetch" href="https://somewhere.tls" crossorigin>` or `<rel="preconnect" href="https://somewhere.tls" crossorigin> <rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://somewhere.tls">`

Comment: @retrovertigo apparently, use two separate tags to avoid a safari bug: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71584173/5240159