# Is there a limit to how many domains we should "dns-prefetch preconnect" with Chrome?

Tags: google-chrome, web-performance, preconnect

When we want to make sure a blazing fast website who uses third-party widgets/plugins/add-ons/analytics etc.. One of the many requirements to achieve this is to "dns-prefetch preconnect" for each individual domain name (basically saving a little for the DNS lookups etc.)

I could not find a document that would advise how many domain names we could "dns-prefetch preconnect" before we lose any potential benefit. Remember how in the old times Internet Explorer had a limit to how many images could be downloaded in parallel, just wonder if Chrome could have some reasoning for limiting "dns-prefetch preconnect" request?

> For example: how many is too many?

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://admin.typeform.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://api.amplitude.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://api.segment.io" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://app.launchdarkly.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://bam.nr-data.net" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://cdn.amplitude.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://cdn.segment.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://customer.api.drift.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://embed.typeform.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://event.api.drift.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://events.launchdarkly.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://images.typeform.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://js-agent.newrelic.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://js.driftt.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://load.sumo.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://metrics.api.drift.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://renderer-assets.typeform.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://static.addtoany.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://sumo.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://weclean1.typeform.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://www.google-analytics.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://www.googletagmanager.com" crossorigin />
<link rel="dns-prefetch preconnect" href="https://www.youtube.com" crossorigin />
```

Any links feedback/advice is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 14, accepted):

## Resource hints shouldn't be over-used

First, as mentioned below, you should prefer `preload`. If you don't know exactly what resources your page will include, the `dns-prefetch` and `preconnect` can be appropriate.

The [resource hint specification](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/) [indicates](https://www.w3.org/TR/resource-hints/#preconnect) that the optimal number of connections is highly contingent:

> The optimal number of connections per origin is dependent on the
>   negotiated protocol, users current connectivity profile, available
>   device resources, global connection limits, and other context specific
>   variables. As a result, the decision for how many connections should
>   be opened is deferred to the user agent.

Both `dns-prefetch` and `preconnect` indicate the user agent "should" initiate the process, which means they don't have to do so.

Ilya Grigorik, the editor of that spec, [says](https://www.igvita.com/2015/08/17/eliminating-roundtrips-with-preconnect/)

> That said, use it wisely: each open socket incurs costs both on the
>   client and server, and you want to avoid opening sockets that might go
>   unused. As always, apply, measure real-world impact, and iterate to
>   get the best performance mileage from this feature.

Sérgio Gomes, also a Googler, [echos](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization) Ilya's warning with a bit more specificity:

> Bear in mind that while `<link rel="preconnect">` is pretty cheap, it
>   can still take up valuable CPU time, particularly on secure
>   connections. This is especially bad if the connection isn’t used
>   within 10 seconds, as the browser closes it, wasting all of that early
>   connection work.
>
> In general, try to use `<link rel="preload">` wherever you can, as it’s
>   a more comprehensive performance tweak, but do keep `<link rel="preconnect">` in your toolbelt for the edge cases.

Sérgio continues to illustrate a couple examples where `preconnect`, rather than `preload`, is appropriate. I highly recommend [taking a look](https://developers.google.com/web/fundamentals/performance/resource-prioritization#use-case_knowing_where_from_but_not_what_youre_fetching) at those.

[Ivan Akulov](https://iamakulov.com/), former Googler and current web performance startup CEO, [ventures a numerical recommendation](https://3perf.com/blog/link-rels/):

> You want to speed up more than 4-6 domains. It’s not recommended to use  `<link rel="preconnect" />` with more than 4-6 domains, as opening and keeping a connection is an expensive operation. `<link rel="dns-prefetch" />` is more lightweight, so use it for other third-party domains if you want to speed them up too.

But Ivan, though a reputable source, doesn't provide hard technical support for this recommendation.

Without reading the source code for each relevant browser, it's impossible to defensibly say how many dns-prefetch/preconnects are too many. Even after reading source code, it can only offer a hint as to how many are appropriate. There is no hard limit, but the authoritative sources above give us reason to be cautious.

## But it's difficult to know where to draw the line

There's only one way to improve performance:

1. decide which metrics matter to you and your users
2. use the best available synthetic and real-user numbers to measure the status quo
3. make changes and measure the difference

It would take a number of iterations to land on the best possible configuration. And the optimal hint selection could change over time. From a maintainability perspective, it would be best to aggressively preconnect everything that meets Sérgio's "edge case" requirements, and trust the browser to do its job. But again, never without testing.

## A couple other notes

That's a lot of third-party dependencies for that page. I'm sure you're working within your requirements, but this may be a great time to ask management to re-evaluate the necessity of some of those.

Finally, keep in mind that [`crossorigin` isn't appropriate for every resource hint](https://crenshaw.dev/preconnect-resource-hint-crossorigin-attribute). It depends on whether the resource(s) to be downloaded will use CORS. If you don't know, that could double the number of preconnects needed.

> The `crossorigin` attribute, when used with `rel="preconnect"`, doesn't
>   describe where the target origin is but rather what kind of assets
>   will be downloaded from that origin. If the assets use CORS,
>   `crossorigin` is needed. If CORS won't be used, `crossorigin` should be
>   omitted. If both types of assets will be present, two resource hints
>   are necessary.

Take a look at this [list of resources that use CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/CORS#What_requests_use_CORS) for guidance.

Comment: Thanks, Michael, yes for my case I do not (want to) know continuously exactly what resources the page will include. This is indeed a complex matter and I was mostly looking for a best advise compromise on a number of connections from Chrome's perspective. +1

Comment: Fair enough! I hate that the answers to this kind of question are often so fuzzy. But the Chrome team rolls out features so quickly, I’m sure they don’t often get the chance to go back and talk about the finer points.

Comment: After some tests, I settled for up to 5. Any more advice from Chrome would be beneficial too. Cheers!

Comment: Until we know any better I have accepted your answer which could definitely set people in the right direction. For the time being more tests would be needed. Thanks again!

Comment: This is a good response but it doesn't _really_ answer the question ;)

Comment: @RickDavies thanks! Unfortunately, not all answers are scalars. Some are more like functions.

Answer (score 2):

Also be aware of this bug if you care about Safari:

https://web.dev/preconnect-and-dns-prefetch/

> Browser support for dns-prefetch is slightly different from preconnect support, so dns-prefetch can serve as a fallback for browsers that don't support preconnect.
>
> ```
> <link rel="preconnect" href="http://example.com">
> <link rel="dns-prefetch" href="http://example.com">
> ```
>
> Recommended — To safely implement the fallback technique use separate
>   link tags.
>
> ```
> <link rel="preconnect dns-prefetch" href="http://example.com">
> ```
>
> Not recommended — Implementing dns-prefetch fallback in the same
>    tag causes a bug in Safari where preconnect gets cancelled.

Answer (score 2):

There was a limit of six concurrent DNS lookups in older Chrome versions. As of Chrome version 26 for Windows, Mac, and Linux, there is an asynchronous DNS resolver, which effectively removed that limit (or perhaps just increased it):

> *"6 DNS requests is no longer true with async DNS resolver, but your point still stands.. we limit number of inflight resolves.*" — **Ilya Grigorik**, Web performance engineer at Google ([via Twitter](https://twitter.com/igrigorik/status/1024015675583389696))

Answer (score 1):

I am fairly new and unable to add a comment yet, so adding an answer instead.

From my own tests, Chrome seems to have a [TTL of 1000 in the DNS Cache](https://superuser.com/questions/1277057/why-does-chrome-have-ttl-1000-in-the-dns-cache)
This may be the reason that when opening "too early" a `"dns-prefetch preconnect"` connection may in fact turn out to have a negative impact on desired performance.

You could also check [preconnect vs dns-prefetch resource hints](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47273743/preconnect-vs-dns-prefetch-resource-hints)

> "TTL" is an abbreviation for: Time To Live