# Do not request https://fonts.gstatic.com

Tags: fonts, pagespeed-insights

I am trying to speed up my website and want to get rid off some https://fonts.gstatic.com requestes.
For instance, PageSpeed Insights gives me a warning about "Make sure all text remains visible while loading the web fonts" about https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2

While gtmetrix is displaying this request instead:
https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxK.woff2

Do not know why they are different, but how can I omit this type of request?
I can not find these text strings when I search for them in my WordPress public_html directory using SSH.

PageSpeed Insights :
[image]

Gtmetrix:

[image]

Comment: I was also trying to do same but for a flutter project, i.e. getting rid of online fonts, and putting in local dir.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> want to get rid off some https://fonts.gstatic.com requests

If you are using Google Fonts, then you cannot. Gstatic.com is a domain that Google owns and uses to serve static content. See [this answer on SuperUser](https://superuser.com/a/64724/859609).

> PageSpeed Insights gives me a warning about "Make sure all text remains visible while loading the web fonts"

I hope you have read the [documentation](https://web.dev/font-display/).
When using Google Fonts, add the `&display=swap` parameter to the end of the Google Fonts URL.

The good news is, following the instructions on Google Fonts will generally handle things for you.
[image: Instructions demo]

### Continue reading [iff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/If_and_only_if) the above could not satisfy you

For further speedups and/or customization (e.g. [reducing the number of preconnects](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55815539/8659747)), this is how I handle the issue.

Suppose I want to use the font [`Comfortaa`](https://fonts.google.com/share?selection.family=Comfortaa).

```html
 <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
```

Instead of linking the remote CSS file at https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Comfortaa&display=swap, I visit the URL, download the CSS file to the server and link to that instead.
This gets rid of the delay caused while establishing connections to `fonts.googleapis.com`.

**Warning:**
The CSS files provided by Google Fonts may be changed in future.
It is your responsibility to update those files when modified by Google Fonts.

Answer (score 0):

can you add this line.

```
<link rel="preload" as="font" type="font/woff2" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com/s/roboto/v18/KFOmCnqEu92Fr1Mu4mxKKTU1Kg.woff2" crossorigin>
```