# DNS-prefetch and preconnect: Only for non-cached resources?

Tags: caching, prefetch, preconnect, dns-prefetch

This is a question about `dns-prefetch` and `preconnect`, and possible optimizations:

- If a resource is cached, are `dns-prefetch` and `preconnect` still doing their job?
- If not, is it possible to optimize this behavior so that `dns-prefetch` and `preconnect` do their job only for non-cached resources?

Comment: [An answer on another tread](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51059127/3025856) suggests not using `preconnect` for static resources that are _likely_ going to be cached (e.g., from a CDN) since you’ll be establishing the connection without ever needing it. In that case, however, `dns-prefetch` remains useful as it’s a much cheaper operation, and the results are cached.