# dns-prefetch + preconnect vs. browser cache

Tags: performance, preconnect, dns-prefetch

To improve the page load time I want to use `dns-prefetch` and `preconnect` for external javascripts.

```
<link rel="dns-prefetch" href="https://example.com">
<link rel="preconnect" href="https://example.com">
```

What happen if the ressource (in my case the external javascript) is already in the browser cache? Do `dns-prefetch` and `preconnect` add page load time unnecessarily? In other words: Are `dns-prefetch` and `preconnect` only useful on the first page load?

Comment: What is the benefit of using both dns-prefetch and preconnect? I thought preconnect does dns-prefetch's job (dns-lookup) and some additional stuff

Comment: @ShakKiR yes you so can put preconnect first and then dns-prefetch second as a fallback (opposite to OP.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

On the repeat visit, the preconnect/dns-prefetch will indeed be useless if all resources are taken from cache. But they will not increase page load time. They happen in parallel of page loading, and cache reads do not wait for DNS/TLC/TCP resolution. So the only drawback is that you create unused TCP connection and slightly increase the load on the server.